# $nth$ root of matrices in characteristic $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that for any matrix $A\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$, and any natural number $m$ there exists a matrix $B\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ such that $B^m=A$, can we extend this 
to any algebraically closed field with positive characteristic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. In characteristic $p$, consider a matrix $A$ with all eigenvalues $1$. Assume that $B^p=A$. Then the eigenvalues of $B$ are all $1$  ($x^p - 1=(x-1)^p$), and so $B-I$ is nilpotent. Assume now that $\dim B \le p$. Then $(B-I)^p=0$. However, $(B-I)^p= B^p- I^p = A-I$, and so $A=I$. Hence, a unipotent matrix not identity and of size at most $p$ does not have $p$-th roots.